# ParseXML not returning the content, console shows : (e){return k.each(this,e)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert the content of an XML file to a website. It's also my first time using JQuery, and now I'm stuck.

When I try to get all the  in the XML file, nothing happens and I have no idea why. Maybe the format of my XML file is incorrect? I get this in my console with this command: `console.log($item.each);` = (e){return k.each(this,e)

Here's how I proceed:

```
function RSS(){
    let url = "https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/World.xml";
    $.ajax(url, {
        method: "GET",
        complete: function(obj){
            let xmlContent = obj.responseXML;
            useContent(xmlContent);
        }
        }
    )
}
function useContent(xmlContent){
    let xmlParcours = $.parseXML (xmlContent);
    let $xmlContent = $(xmlParcours);
    let $item = $xmlContent.find("item");
    console.log($item.each);
    $item.each(function(){
        let title = $(this).find('title').text();

        $("#world").append('<h3>' +title+ '</h3>')

    })

}
```

Thanks for the help

Edit: After some tests, this part is never executed, why?:

```
$item.each(function(){
            let title = $(this).find('title').text();
            alert("test")
            $("#world").append('<h3>' +title+ '</h3>')

        })
```

Comment: you can't call 'each' function like above $item.each in the console.log(). comment this line console.log($item.each); then rest of the code will get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified working version:

```js
RSS()

function RSS() {
  let url = "https://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/World.xml";
  $.ajax(url, {
    method: "GET",
    type: 'xml',
    success: useContent

  })
}



function useContent(xmlContent) {

  let $items = $(xmlContent).find("item");

  $items.each(function() {
    let title = $(this).find('title').text();
    console.log(title);
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```